# how to delete Arabic bad code file name with "$'\275'ڵ$'\343'.txt"

Tags: filenames, arabic, file-not-found

it is on ANDROID, from a decompress try by bsdtar on Termux, the bad code file name with 'ls' resulte is like "�ڵ�.txt" (copy&paste), and with 'ls' tab completion is like:

```
$'\275'$J'\343.txt
```

(the J is mimical of the Arabic charactor)

```
$'\275'ڵ$'\343'.txt
```

the above line as contrast BUT in clipboard IT TURNS right to left, it is an "Arabic" bad code file name, my system can't delete or rename it, but dd command CAN dump this file with:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=$'\275'ڵ$'\343'.txt
```

it means dd command can handle the file name

```
find . -inum xxxxxx -exec rm {} \;
```

and

```
rm -rf *
```

All NOT WORK:

'./'$'\275''ڵ'$'\343''.txt': No such file or directory

and
`find . -inum xxxxxx -delete`

find: cannot delete ‘./\275ڵ\343.txt’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find . -inum xxxxxx -delete` instead, it may handle the special characters better.

Comment: Already tried, no work, find: cannot delete ‘./\275ڵ\343.txt’: No such file or directory